# Give an example of a language $A$ that is recursively enumerable but isn't recursive, and a recursive language $B$ such that $A\cap B$ isn't recursive

Tags: computability, turing-machines

> Give an example of a language $A$ that is recursively enumerable but isn't recursive, and a recursive language $B$ such that $A\cap B$ isn't recursive (if possible).

I'm a bit lost here. How do I calculate the intersection between two languages (is that the words that belong in both?)

If a language is R.E. but not recursive what that means is basically that it can fall into an endless loop?

If $A$ is non recursive and $B$ is recursive, the intersection will always be non-recursive. Correct? In that case $B$ could be any recursive language.

How do I solve this?

Comment: No, $A$ is recursive/ r.e. if and only if $2A$ is recursive/re. So if $A$ is r.e. but not recursive, so is $2A,$ and we can take $B=\{\text{odd numbers}\}$ and then $2A\cap B=\emptyset$ is recursive.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you know $A\cap B=\emptyset$ is recursive?

Comment: The empty set is recursive.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In class we learned of a language called Hstop that makes the machine stop, and is r.e. but not recursive. Can A = Hstop ?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How do you know B = {odd numbers} is recursive? How can you be sure it never goes into an infinite loop?

Comment: I suggest you review what recursive means, and basic examples. The odd numbers are clearly recursive. What “it” do you think might go into an infinite loop? Note, I mean $B$ is all odd positive integers.

Comment: See the list of "Related" questions. There's one specifically about "recursively enumerable, but not recursive".

Comment: Making any progress, Seg?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. The exam was today and this exact question came up. I gave Thomas's answer.